# How to compute "normalized" frequency from Mel Spectrogram?

Tags: python, spectrogram, librosa

I have computed the mel spectrogram with librosa like that:

```
self.Spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=self.RawSignal, sr=self.sampling_frequency,
                                                      n_mels=128, fmax=8000)
```

I need to obtain the corresponding value of a given frequency (say 4400 Hz) in the normalized scale [0,127], since `n_mels=128`. I have seen that 103 is the corresponding value to 4400 Hz, but I would like a generic formula. 
PS. it is not the conversion formula from Hz to mels what I am searching for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [librosa.core.mel_frequencies](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.mel_frequencies.html?highlight=mel_frequencies#librosa.core.mel_frequencies) function to calculate the centerpoint of your mel filters. Make sure to pass the same parameters as to `melspectrogram`. Once you have the centerpoints, you can find which bin a particular frequency belongs to by looking up the closest value.

```
import numpy
import librosa

find = 4400 
freqs = librosa.core.mel_frequencies(fmin=0.0, fmax=8000, n_mels=128)
bin = numpy.argmin(abs(freqs - find))

print(bin)
```

103